# Swift casting unsafemutablepointer<MyStruct> to C void return pointer in swift

Tags: swift, swift2

I have a struct type in C and swift creates a struct pointer var from the C definition - that part works fine.

I have a C function that returns a void pointer to a C struct of the same type.

The problem is that the C void pointer returned doesn't cast across to the receiving swift structure pointer. I can't figure out how to cast it or convert it. What am I missing?

**C HEADER**

```
void* MyCFunc(int input);
struct MyStruct
{
   int ID;
   int thisOne;
   float thatOne;
} MyStruct;
```

**SWIFT CALLING CODE**

```
var ptr:UnsafePointer<MyStruct>
ptr = MyCFunc(5)                   //Error Here
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

look at this 'self explanatory' example

```
struct MyStruct {
    var myId: Int
    var myDouble: Double
}

var myStruct = MyStruct(myId: 1, myDouble: 1.0)

// this mimics the funcion which returns Void *myStruct
var vptr = withUnsafeMutablePointer(&myStruct) { (pStruct) -> UnsafeMutablePointer<Void> in
    return UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>(pStruct)
}
print(vptr) // 0x00000001079c7828
// mimics mPtr =  (MyStruct *) vptr
let mPtr = UnsafeMutablePointer<MyStruct>(vptr) // UnsafeMutablePointer(0x10EE37838)

mPtr.memory.myId = 10
mPtr.memory.myDouble = 10.0

print(myStruct) // MyStruct(myId: 10, myDouble: 10.0)
```